# IdentityServer with SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime increasingly adds to token expiration

Tags: c#, identityserver4, refresh-token

I've been fine-tuning my client registration in IdentityServer 4.x and I've encountered a situation I cannot see a solution to.

First of, I'm implementing a strategy where I rotate my refresh tokens, so I set them to `OneTime` usage. In addition I set `AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime` to zero (0), and `RefreshTokenExpiration` to `Sliding`, with a `SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime` of e.g. 24 hours.

According to documentation this results in a configuration where the refresh tokens can be used only *one time* and when they are used they are getting a new expiration time.

> when refreshing the token, the lifetime of the refresh token will be renewed (by the amount specified in SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime). The lifetime will not exceed AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime.

Also, **mderriey** has a nice explanation here which uses time-variables: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2411#issuecomment-171483658

However, there is one statement that does not match what's happening on my side, and that is regarding the new expiration of the refresh token:

> You use it at time T8 to get a new access token. Its new expiration time is T18

In my case the new expiration time is **T22**. The `SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime` is appended to *how much time is remaining* on the used refresh token.

So, I'm in a situation where I have configured my client, and every time a refresh token is used the newly created refresh tokens are getting increasingly longer and longer expiration times.

From the logs:

```
// This is where the token is first created
2022-03-08 15:59:23.783 +00:00 [DBG] Creating refresh token
2022-03-08 15:59:23.784 +00:00 [DBG] Setting a sliding lifetime: 86400
// First time the refresh token is used
2022-03-08 16:51:07.573 +00:00 [DBG] Updating refresh token
2022-03-08 16:51:07.574 +00:00 [DBG] Token usage is one-time only. Setting current handle as consumed, and generating new handle
2022-03-08 16:51:07.579 +00:00 [DBG] ubeVQ9IFAHEFfNRXHcCj22q3TpYCn4il2IAV7E1FbBQ= found in database
2022-03-08 16:51:07.605 +00:00 [DBG] Refresh token expiration is sliding - extending lifetime
2022-03-08 16:51:07.606 +00:00 [DBG] Current lifetime: 3104
2022-03-08 16:51:07.607 +00:00 [DBG] New lifetime: 89504
// 2nd time the refresh token is used
2022-03-08 17:42:08.671 +00:00 [DBG] Updating refresh token
2022-03-08 17:42:08.672 +00:00 [DBG] Token usage is one-time only. Setting current handle as consumed, and generating new handle
2022-03-08 17:42:08.678 +00:00 [DBG] jU3/t8Y0yolEA7viiPcAj5v0wVQWoviNjjfLS3atfhA= found in database
2022-03-08 17:42:08.701 +00:00 [DBG] Refresh token expiration is sliding - extending lifetime
2022-03-08 17:42:08.702 +00:00 [DBG] Current lifetime: 6165
2022-03-08 17:42:08.702 +00:00 [DBG] New lifetime: 92565
```

As you can see, the refresh token is getting increasingly longer and longer expiration.

Is there some class or interface I can implement where I can handle this and *cap* the new expiration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that most of the properties of the original refresh token is re-used when creating a new refresh token when set to `OneTime` usage. This **includes** the `CreationTime` which is the timestamp used when calculating lifetime.

An observant eye might notice that the new lifetimes mentioned in the logs equals `Current lifetime` + 86400.

Since `CreationTime` doesn't change, the value of lifetime grows over time, because it's the number of seconds since that specific time.

I mistakenly thought that `CreationTime` reflected the timestamp of the newly created record in `PersistedGrants`.